# vue-js button element with no type --> submit

Tags: vue.js, button, form-submit

We have been having a very strange problem in a vue-js (@vue-cli, Build version) application. There was a button in App.vue that had an onclick

> `<button @click="goIRList" id="irlistBtn">IR List</button>`

that was working for fine for some users, every time, and not others. For the others, I checked (with alerts) that the goIRList code was not reached at all. These others had this issue with any browser we tried. They did *not* have the issue when Vue+Developer Tools was open - making it harder for me to debug it.

Instead of the goIRList code, these users got a page with just the error message

> `Cannot GET /menu.csp`

That was especially perplexing, because menu.csp is code from a completely different system, though one also associated with the same computer. It is never referenced in the vue-js application.
Eventually I realized that what was happening was a *submit*, even though the button was not in any form on the page [I had thought that a button is only a submit type by default, if it is inside a form]. As soon as I added a type, <button type="button"...>, the issue went away completely.
Could someone explain why this was happening? And why did it work for some users? Thanks!

Update: and now the problem is back, same conditions: for them and not for me. Nothing changed. I also added .prevent to the button's onclick:

> <button type="button" @click.prevent="goIRList" id="irlistBtn">IR List

and no help. So maybe that wasn't the issue. Anyhow, now I'm asking for a fix as well as an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: is the button is the child of a form?

Comment: Not one of mine. Since it was the vue-js Build version, I don't really know what was in the final page. Does vue-js add a "form" wrapper or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And someone pointed out the answer to me. Ridiculous: those two buttons were hidden underneath a logo image that was higher up on the page. It was the image that contained the bogus link.
I never got the error, because I can't see so well, so I keep the sizing high, and the buttons were far away from the logo. Others had a more normal page sizing, and everything got smaller except for that image; the invisible margin of the image went over the buttons, and someone trying to click on the buttons triggered the link.
I set the image to resize with the page and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "submit" event catcher in the form, and prevent the default action.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form @submit="submit">
      <input value="Tom">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Success!");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Again, the problem was solved already by just adding the button type. I could have blocked the submit the way you said as well. My question was, why did it happen?

Comment: See update on post: problem is back, _even_ with a .prevent